# Make an href if condition is met in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have different text that will be displayed in my template based on what gets returned from a service.  Let's say: Initializing, Running, Done.  In Angular, how do I make the text a link if the word matches Done?

```
$scope.status = // Initializing, Running, or Done based on service
```

In the template, I want to show

> {{ status }}

but when the status is Done, I want a hyperlink to go the actual result.  Do I need to use an ng-if, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-show` and `ng-hide` to logically render what you want to show on your view.

In your case, you want to `ng-show` the link when `status == 'Done'` and `ng-hide` any other status when `status == 'Done'`

Here is a simple fiddle to illustrate https://jsfiddle.net/48fsbqvb/